# Print a list of numbers in python with different delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to print numbers in python as integers but with different delimiters depending on the position in the list if there is only one number in the list it should print like this: 1 otherwise if there are multiple numbers the following pattern is used:

5:7!11&13:17!19&23

I have the printing and the delimiter part correct but it is a list and it is a list of strings. Here is the code:

```
primen = [5,7,11,13,17,19,23]
prime_out = []
prime_str = [str(item) for item in  primen]

prime_len = len(prime_str)
if (prime_len ==  0):
      print ("No Primes")
      exit()    

for k in range(0,prime_len): 
    if   k == prime_len - 1:
           prime_out.append(prime_str[k])
           print(prime_out)
    else:
          if  lng ==  0:
                prime  =  prime_str[k] + ":"  
                prime_out.append(prime)
                lng =  lng + 1                 
          elif lng == 1:
                prime  =  prime_str[k] + "!"
                prime_out.append(prime)
                lng = lng + 1                     
          elif  lng ==  2:
                prime  =   prime_str[k] + "&"
                prime_out.append(prime)                   
                lng = 0
```

and my output looks like this: ['5:', '7!', '11&', '13:', '17!', '19&', '23']
How do I get it to look like I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "join" like this:

```
output = ['5:', '7!', '11&', '13:', '17!', '19&', '23']
print("".join(output))
```

And the result is:

```
5:7!11&13:17!19&23
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thank you.